# Unable to execute pure UPDATE query in Django

Tags: mysql, django

When I try to execute a trivial `UPDATE` query in a table with just one row, I get `OperationalError` with value `1205, Lock wait timeout exceeded`. I do it like this:

```
import MySQLdb
... other imports

def test(request):
    db = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1","root","root","reestr")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("UPDATE object_1_ SET attr_13_ = 'value'")
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    return HttpResponse(True)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use django's functions?

Comment: Well, I like Django, but I hate ORM =)

Comment: Hm, I added `db.close()` and now it seems to work.